# FileNotFound error in Google Colab when creating CSV files

Tags: python, pandas, csv, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to split a Pandas dataframe into smaller CSV files in Google Colab. I thought a new CSV file would automatically be created if it did not exist once writerow is called, but I'm getting the FileNotFound error. Any pointers on what I could have overlooked?

I'm not quite sure how to write to files in Google Colab—it doesn't seem to work. Additionally, would the use of iloc here be correct?

```
csv_counter = 1
for ind in bottle.index:
  try:
    if bottle['u'][ind] == 1 and bottle['u'][ind+1]==bottle['u'][ind]:
      f = "/content/drive/MyDrive/proj/datasets/036/{}.csv".format(csv_counter)
      csv_new = open(f, "w")    
      writer = csv.writer(csv_new)
      writer.writerow(bottle.iloc[ind])

    elif bottle['u'][ind] == 1:
      writer.writerow(bottle.iloc[ind])
      csv_counter += 1

  except:
    f = "/content/drive/MyDrive/proj/datasets/036/{}.csv".format(csv_counter)
    csv_new = open(f, "w")    
    writer = csv.writer(csv_new)
    writer.writerow(bottle.iloc[ind])
```

Comment: This logic seems quite tortured and repetitive. Without access to your data, we can't guess which code path gets executed, and we obviously can't see which files and directories exist on your side. Please reveiew the guidance for providing a [mre] and [edit] accordingly; please include the full traceback.

Comment: A simple common beginner error is attempting to create a file in a directory whica doesn't exist; this would produce the same error message.